# Is there any software that can reduce the buzzing sound i hear in the background on my headphones

Tags: audio, headphones

Is there any software that can reduce the buzzing sound i hear in the background on my headphones

Just what the title says :D

Comment: Looks like it is an issue with your headphones.

Comment: Depends on what the source of the buzzing is. But regardless, software recommendation questions are off-topic.

Comment: This is almost certainly a hardware problem, and the solution will be better quality equipment.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. Are you using a lead to extend the length of the cord? If so please t may be the connection. If you find that by wiggling the jack,the buzzing goes away for a bit,it is the connection. Either buy better quality extender leads or better headphones